# Android Google Play Leaderboards

Tags: android, google-play-games

I am developing an Android game that is using the Google Play Leaderboard functionality. The game consists of weekly tournaments, with the player gaining the highest score during the Leaderboard 'week' (which ends at 11:59:00 PST on Sunday), winning the tournament.

Is there a way to utilize the Google Play Leaderboard API to query information such as highest scores for the PAST week for the same Leaderboard? Can you query Leaderboards for a specific time range?

I have only seen options to query Leaderboards for the current day, current week, and all-time. Any insight into this would be much appreciated.

Comment: The API documentation says that "Daily leaderboards reset at midnight PST every day, and *weekly leaderboards reset at Saturday midnight PST*". I don't think there's a default way to access past scores beyond all time high scores, you'd have to store the information and query it yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the comment -- this is exactly the approach that I am going to have to take.

Comment: No problem, good luck.